# How to keep bootstrap row height the same while button appears/dissappears

Tags: html, css, angularjs, twitter-bootstrap

I'm using `AngularJS` and Bootstrap to create a dynamic form. I want to make an `'edit' button` appear whenever the user hovers over a row of the form. The problem is that the row is growing and shrinking when the button appears/disappears respectively and I want to keep it the same regardless.

Setting the minimum height for the row would seem to be the answer i.e.:

```
ng-style="{'min-height': '40px'}"
```

But adding that to the 'div class="row"' element breaks the code, see the corresponding [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/m2k5oher/39/).

Anyone know where I'm going wrong and can suggest a good solution to the problem?

Comment: The fiddle doesn't seem to work. I get no button when i hover the rows. Have you tried "line-height" instead of "min-height"? Since the fiddle doesn't work I'm not sure but it might work. (I'm using Chrome on Windows and I have also tried in IE11)

Comment: Sorry, I removed the ng-style="{'min-height': '40px'}">' from the template. It should be working now, see [here](https://jsfiddle.net/m2k5oher/40/)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

@user3042437 Yeah, now it works. :) (I'm posting this as an answer instead of a comment)

Well, you have two propblems. The first is that the button is placed on a second row. This can be fixed by adding the following css:

```
.row > div {
    display: inline-block;
}
```

The second is that you're using Bootstrap to style your buttons and they are quite big. Use "btn-link" instead of "btn" as the class of your buttons and then remove their border and padding on top and button by using this css:

```
.btn-link {
    padding-top: 0;
    padding-bottom: 0;
    border: 0;
}
```

I hope this works for you :)

Answer (score 2):

Give the row a padding and the button a negative margin bottom to match, like you would when sticking the footer at the bottom of the page.